# How to get error of execvp in the fork()?

Tags: c, fork, execvp

I have the following code.

My question is in the code

```
     int main() {

            ....

         if ((uproc.pid = fork()) == -1) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (uproc.pid == 0) {
            /* child */

            const char *argv[3];
            int i = 0;
            argv[i++] = "/bin/sh";
            argv[i++] =  "/my/script.sh";
            argv[i++] = NULL;

            execvp(argv[0], (char **) argv);
            exit(ESRCH);

        } else if (uproc.pid < 0)
            return -1;

        /* parent */
        int status;
        while (wait(&status) != uproc.pid) {
            DD(DEBUG,"waiting for child to exit");
        }

           // If /my/script.sh exit accidentally in some place with error. 
           // can I catch this error right here?
          ......
    }
```

Comment: You get in by the `wait` function, it's in the `status` variable.

Comment: it could be a response to my question

Comment: status is always 0. in case there is no error and in case there is an error in the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exit status of the child is provided by the `wait` function, in the `status` variable.

You get the exit status by using the `WEXITSTATUS` macro, but only if the program exited normally (i.e. called `exit` or returned from its `main` function):

```
if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("Child exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
else
    printf("Child exited abnormally\n");
```

Read the [manual page for `wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for more information.

Comment: From the OP it is not clear ("*... get the error of the cmd executed ...*") if its really the exit code which is wanted. Anyway 1+, as thats all one could get.

Comment: my script exit in the middle with message error because there is a fault in the middle. The status return always 0 (in cas there is error in the script and in cas there is no)

Comment: So why not change this and let your script use `exit 0` only in case of success and on any error call `exit` with an argument different from `0`. @MohamedKALLEL

Comment: To make the script react on abnormal terminations of processes started fby the script you could uses a `trap`. An interesting article on makeing your scripts more robust could be found here: http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html @MohamedKALLEL