# C/C++ program to return output (int) to other program

Tags: c++, c, binary, return-value, executable

I want to create a program in C/C++ which calls other program(which is compiled to binary already) and use its "exit status" (or return value which is int type) for some other operation.
Both programs are written in C/C++, and are to be build in separate binary executables.
I want a simple code for both of them.
Please also tell the include files to be used for linux/windows for the above program. Thanks

Comment: see the following link, It could give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532391/how-to-get-error-of-execvp-in-the-fork

Comment: Did you try anything? Even, did you read any documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have app1 and app2.

then use the C++ system() function and assign its return value to an integer.

eg:
code for app1:

```
#include <cstdlib>

// code code code ...

int exit_status = system("app2");

// more code
```

exit_status will take the value that is returned from app2's main() function.

Comment: Thanks got it. Cant vote You up, require at least 15 reputations for it :(. Surely will vote when I get.

Comment: YOU CAN ACCEPT HIS ANSWER; YOU HAVE THE PRIVELEGES FOR THAT