# Return status of execve

Tags: c, process, exec

I want to send exit status 0 from the execve process to the process which started it.
Because on Success execve never returns, So I am not able to do anything after that. But I want if execve ran successful.

Comment: this link could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532391/how-to-get-error-of-execvp-in-the-fork

Comment: The OP wants the parent to know that a child's `exec` proceeded successfully. An `exec` failure can be reported to the parent in a number of ways (through a pipe, or with a special exit status), but `exec` success is harder to confirm, because successful `exec` by definition means that our process is no longer running.

Comment: @user4815162342: With "*... a child's `exec` ...*" you mean the `exec` that created the child itself or an `exec` done by a child (which turn had been create by an `exec` by the parent)?

Comment: @alk `exec` doesn't create a child, `fork` does. By "child's `exec`" I mean "`exec` performed in the child process".

Comment: @user4815162342: Oh yes sure, suffered a temp brain laps ... sry.

Comment: @alk No problem. This a good question hindered by very un-eloquent phrasing that makes it look like noise.

Answer (score 6):

You can verify that exec *succeeded* using `FD_CLOEXEC`:

- create a pipe.
- fork.
- in the child, close the read end of the pipe and set the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag on the write end of the pipe. Then proceed with `exec`. If `exec` succeeds, the pipe will be automatically closed due to `FD_CLOEXEC`. If `exec` fails, write a byte to the pipe and exit.
- in the parent, close the write end of the pipe and read from the read end. If you read 0 bytes (EOF), it means that `exec` succeeded. If you read a byte in the pipe, it means that `exec` failed.

The data written over the pipe in case of failure can be used to transmit error information, such as value of `errno` after `exec`.

The code, with error checking omitted for brevity, would look like this:

```
int pipe_fds[2];
pipe(pipe_fds);
if (!fork()) {
  close(pipe_fds[0]);
  fcntl(pipe_fds[1], F_SETFD, F_CLOEXEC);
  execve(...);
  write(pipe_fds[1], "", 1);
  _exit(1);
}
else {
  int n;
  char out;
  close(pipe_fds[1]);
  n = read(pipe_fds[0], &out, 1);
  if (n == 0)
    printf("exec successful\n");
  else
    printf("exec failed\n");
  close(pipe_fds[0]);
}
```

Note that this technique can be unsafe if other threads may exec their own processes in parallel. The issue is that there is a delay between when the pipe is created and when the close-on-exec flag gets set. If an unrelated thread forks and execs during that critical window, the child will inherit `pipe_fds[1]` and won't close it, causing the parent to hang. This can be fixed using the Linux-specific [`pipe2`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe2) call which allows atomically creating the pipe with the close-on-exec flag set.

Comment: On failure to `exec`, is it guaranteed that the SIGCHLD signal will be delivered before the EOF notification from the fact that that the child dying closed the pipe?  I like the idea behind the technique; I'm just wondering if there's a race condition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think there's any such guarantee, but it shouldn't be necessary. It is easy enough to disambiguate by sending some data through the pipe if `exec` fails.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've now edited the answer to no longer rely on `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: @user4815162342 What happens if this code is executed from two threads. I guess that CLOEXEC will close the file descriptor on the first succeeded exec. If that exec happens from the other thread, it will look like exec succeeded.

Comment: @user877329 I'm not sure this is actually an issue. An exec that happens from another thread would have to fork first, and it would just close its view of file descriptor. The first thread's parent would only observe EOF after _both_ children closed the pipe, so everything would work fine.

Comment: @user877329 I think the inverse can be an issue: if an unrelated thread forks and execs after the pipe is created, but before close-on-exec is set, its view of the file descriptor (created via `fork()`) won't close, so the `read()` in the parent would actually hang! This can be fixed using the Linux-specific [`pipe2`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe2) call which allows atomically creating the pipe with the close-on-exec flag set.

Answer (score 2):

to wait you process launched by `fork()` finish, you can use `wait()`:

```
/* parent */
int status;
while (wait(&status) != uproc.pid) {
    printf("waiting for child to exit");
    }
```

and based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532391/how-to-get-error-of-execvp-in-the-fork)

The exit status of the child is provided by the `wait` function, in the `status` variable.

You get the exit status by using the `WEXITSTATUS` macro, but only if the program exited normally (i.e. called `exit` or returned from its `main` function):

```
if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("Child exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
else
    printf("Child exited abnormally\n");
```

Comment: This won't verify that `exec` *succeeded*, only that the program exited with a successful status. When execing a long-running program, this can make the difference.